# angular testbed : "Can't resolve all parameters for ..." despite providers

Tags: angular, testbed

for all my components who have dependencies in their constructor, when I do the "compileComponents"  I have an error :
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AsciiCharacterComponent: (?).

I include those dependencies with providers:

```
someMock = {...}
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AsciiCharacterComponent, AsciiComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SomeService,
          useValue: someMock
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
```

note that if I use:

```
providers: [SomeService]
```

It work.

Any idea?

Comment: I suspect a circular dependency error. Where is someMock stored and referenced? Does the scenario work with  provide: SomeService,  useValue: null?

Comment: someMock is defined in the same file by a someMock = {}, that is not the issue

Comment: What are the exact dependencies for the components you added in declarations?